# Resolving C++ constructor & call ambiguity

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, ambiguity

I have a nice and small jack-of-all trades Array type that fits all my needs until now.

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
    ...

public:
    int Data; // custom value
    virtual void InitData() { Data = 0; }

    Array(const Array& array);
    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value, U>> Array(const Array<U>& array);
    template <typename... Ts> Array(const Ts&... items);

    void Add(const T& item);
    template <typename... Ts> void Add(const T& item, const Ts&... rest);
    void Add(const Array& array);
}
```

The `template <typename... Ts> Array(const Ts&... items);` lets me do `Array<T> array = { ... }`, and to assign and return `{...}` initializer lists. Because none of the constructors are explicit, it is incredibly convenient, but is also the reason I'm stuck now.

I would like to be able to add anything "reasonable" to the arrays. My main use case right now is:

```
using Curve = Array<float2>;

class Poly   : public Array<float2> { using Array::Array; void InitData() override { Data = 1; } };
class Curve2 : public Array<float2> { using Array::Array; void InitData() override { Data = 2; } };
class Curve3 : public Array<float2> { using Array::Array; void InitData() override { Data = 3; } };
```

The `std::is_same<>` stuff above is specifically to be able to treat all the curves as the same but not the same: the curve types of different degree, and everything is nicely "statically typed", so all I do in a function like `DrawCurve(const Curve&)` is check the degree and then take appropriate action. `Curve` is a nice alias for Array, and Curve2 etc. are degree specializations. It works very nicely.

When I get into curve construction, I usually have a curve object, to which I add *either points or curve segments*. So I'd like to be able to do:

```
Curve3 curve;
curve.Add(float2()); // ambiguity
curve.Add(Array<float2>());
```

Unfortunately, I get an ambiguity here when I call add, because Add() will take either a `float2` or an `Array<float2>`, which works fine, but an Array has the implicit constructor `template <typename... Ts> Array(const Ts&...)`, which can take `float2` as an argument. So the ambiguity is between

```
Array::Add(float2()); // and
Array::Add(Array<float2>(float2()));
```

I have tried making constructors that take arrays explicit, like

```
template <typename A, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<A, Array>::value, A>>
void Add(const Array& array);
```

But then I get new conversion errors from Curve3 to float2 etc. and it becomes a mess.

My hope is that somewhere in the depths of templates or other C++ goodies lies a simple solution that is just what I need. (Yes, I know that I can just rename the methods ::AddItem() and ::AddArray() and the problem will be over in a second, but I don't want this because eventually I want to double all this with `+=` and then mostly just use that.

Any ideas?

Comment: just plugged the code in [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beaea40305a2119f), there doesn't seem to be an ambuiguity between those two adds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that you want

```
 template <typename... Ts> Array(const Ts&... items);
```

to be used only if the parameter pack contains at least one item, and that item's type is not an `Array` template instance. If the parameter pack is empty, this becomes a default constructor, so let's handle this case separately. Go ahead and explicitly define a default constructor, if you need to, and have it do what it needs to do; now we can eliminate that possibility from this use case, and forge ahead.

Having gotten that out of the way, what you want to do here is to use this constructor only when it has one argument:

```
 template <typename T1, typename... Ts> Array(const T1 &t1, const Ts&... items);
```

You will have to modify this constructor to use the explicit `t1`, in addition to the existing parameter pack it uses. That should be simple enough, but that won't be sufficient. There's still ambiguity. You want to have this constructor selected only if T1 is not an `Array`.

There's probably a way to come up with something convoluted and stuff it into a single `std::enable_if`, and shove it into this template. But for clarity, and simplicity, I would use a helper class:

```
template<typename T> class is_not_array : public std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
class is_not_array<Array<T>> : public std::false_type {};
```

And then add a simple `std::enable_if` into this constructor's template to use SFINAE to select this constructor only when its first template parameter is not an `Array`, similar to how you're using `std::enable_if` already, in the other constructor.

This should resolve all ambiguities. This constructor should then be picked only with at least one template parameter that's not an `Array`, with the assistance of this helper class. When it's an `Array`, this constructor will not be resolvable, and that case will go to the other constructor.

I would also suggest using universal references in the templates, instead of `const T &`s.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Template metaprogramming is still very mysterious to me. :)